# How to store only latest key values in a kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a topic that has a stream of data coming to it. What I need is to create a separate topic from this topic that only has the latest set of values given the keys.

I thought a KTable's whole purpose was that it will store the latest value given a key rather than storing the whole stream of events. However I can't seem to get this to work. Running the code below produces the keystore but that keystore (maintopiclatest) has a stream of events in it (not just the latest values). So if I send a request with 1000 records in the topic twice, rather than seeing 1000 records, I see 2000 records.

```
var serializer = new KafkaSpecificRecordSerializer();
var deserializer = new KafkaSpecificRecordDeserializer();

var stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("maintopic",
    Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer)));

var table = stream
    .groupByKey()
    .reduce((aggV, newV) -> newV, Materialized.as("maintopiclatest"));
```

The other problem is if I want to store the KTable in a new topic I'm not sure how to do that. In order to do that it seems that I have to turn it back into a Stream so that I can call ".to" on it. But then that has the whole stream of events in it not just the latest values.

Comment: Why don't you use log compacted topic?

Comment: @Mukeshprajapati That's the first thing I tried but it seems that Log Compaction also doesn't quite work as advertised. It seems that it doesn't kick in immediately regardless of how much I tweaked the various config settings related to it. And I read that it only kicks in under certain conditions after a certain amount of data is present. Then I read about KTables and it made me think they're made exactly for this scenario of wanting only the latest values given the keys. Yet it has all the historical values in it. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how a KTable works.

A KTable itself, has an internal state store and stores exactly one record per key. However, a KTable is constantly updated and subject to the so-called ***stream-table-duality***. Each update to the KTable is sent downstream as a changelog record: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#duality-of-streams-and-tables. Thus, each input record result in an output record.

Because it's stream processing, there is no "last key per value".

> I have a topic that has a stream of data coming to it. What I need is to create a separate topic from this topic that only has the latest set of values given the keys.

At which point in time do you want a KTable to emit an update? There is no answer to this question because the input stream is conceptually infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought the whole purpose of a KTable is similar to a database table to only store the 'latest' value by key. Are you saying this is not possible? I'm very confused reading all the Confluent docs on this then because it makes it sound like a KTable will only have the latest records in it by key as new values come in for those keys. 

But in reality when I consume from the KTable's changelog topic it has every change that comes through in it rather than grouping them by key.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand this. It sounds like the grouping happens on the consumer side. I thought a KTable meant that there will be a different topic in kafka that will store only latest values. So the next question is how do I write code to read from the ktable? I see a ".foreach" method but that's only available if I turn the table back to a stream which I would think would defeat the purpose since that would contain all records instead of just latest ones.

Comment: "I thought the whole purpose of a KTable is similar to a database table to only store the 'latest' value by key" -- that is correct, but you have to think about this as "snapshots" that evolve over time. "I'm very confused" -- that happens ofter -- it's quite a different approach and you need to build up a new mental model (that takes time...) -- also you have to distinguish between the *current* KTable state and it's changelog topic -- the current state stores exactly one record per key -- however, the changelog topic stores updates *over a period of time*.

Comment: Only after a changelog topic is *compacted*, older values are removed and only the newest record per key is preserved. Note, that if you process a KTable, you don't process a snapshot but the changelog topic. -- KTables are materialized client side (by default using RocksDB key-value store). If you want to "point in time" lookups, into the current KTable state, you can use "Interactive Queries": https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: Thanks again for the replies. So if a brand new consumer wants to only consume the 'current' state of affairs, should the consumer be writing code to create a KTable by grouping on key, and then consume the generated changelog topic via the interactive queries? Or am I going down the wrong path? Though you saying by processing a ktable I would process the changelog topic until its compacted makes me think I'm going to be given everything (not just latest data) until it's compacted which may be too late.

Comment: Also when you say "current state stores exactly one record per key", what do you mean precisely by "current state"? Is this referring to something concrete within kafka? Can I access this current state somehow?

Comment: "current state" mean "current state of processing" -- if you do a `builder.table("topic")` by default processing starts at the earliest offset. Thus, the complete topic is consumed and the KTable state is updated and updated and updated during processing. Assuming, that an upstream producer application is constantly writing into `"topic"`, processing never finishes (note, that this is the normal case, because it's stream processing). Thus, during processing the "current state" mean, the state that corresponds to the data from "beginning to current offset" (current offset < topic-end-offset)

Comment: Thus, it's unclear what you mean by "current state of affairs" -- if you assume that no upstream producer is writing into `"topic"`, the KTable won't be updated after the end of the topic is reached (of course, the application is still running waiting for new write to the topic that it would immediately use to update the KTable). At any point in time to you use IQ to query the state and it will return whatever it in the store (depending at what point processing is atm). If no updating happens, you would get the "latest state" obviously.

Comment: Makes sense. So after some time passes and new messages stop coming into the topic and the KTable processing also 'finishes', then I should be able to query the KTable using IQ it sounds like to get the latest values by key (up to that moment in time). What happens if I do a ".toStream()" on the KTable object? Does the resulting stream then have the entire history rather than the most recent values by key?

Comment: Correct. For `toStream()` it give you the complete history (note, that `toStream()` does not start processing when you reach the end of the input topic, but it is running at the same time while the input topic is processed -- it basically create the changelog stream of all table update while processing). If you want to iterator over all keys in the store (for some "snapshot"), you can use IQ via `store.all()`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to write some IQ code to query the store and it did return to me the 'latest' value for a given key once it was finished processing that record.

Comment: @emirhosseini, can you please share your IQ code sample?